# Nested SQL Query

Tags: mysql, join, intersect, subquery

I have the following tables:

> Club:   Club_ID | Title | Created_Date | ...
>
> Club_Intesect: User_ID | Club_ID | Access

I'm trying to select a variable number of clubs, and join the ID of the user with the highest access in that club.  This person is considered the owner.

So if Club 100 has Members A, B, C with access 3,4, and 5 respectively:  I want the final query to select from club:

```
 Club.Club_ID     Club.Title        Club.Created_Date  Club_Intersect.User_ID

      100         |  "Test Club"   |  "Creation Date"     |       C             |
      101         | "Test Club 2"  |  "Creation_Date"     | Highest Access User |
      ...
```

Comment: There is a lot of confusion here. Your results use `Club.Date` and `Club_Intersect.Owner_ID`, neither of which exist in your tables as given. You ask for "highest" access, but select the user with the lowest (3 < 5) in your sample output...

Comment: Your sample table columns don't match the query result columns very well.  Neither 'Club.Date' nor 'Club_Intersect.Owner_ID' is defined.

Comment: Sorry, you're both correct I was careless.  It should make more sense now.

Comment: Can it be assumed that there's only one user with max access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Club c
JOIN Club_Intesect ci ON ci.Club_ID = c.Club_ID
WHERE ci.Access =
    (SELECT MAX(ACCESS)
     FROM Club_Intesect
     WHERE Club_ID = c.Club_ID)
```

Not tested but you get the idea

Comment: Since the desired result is 3, not 5, you probably need MIN rather than MAX.

Comment: ...I think the desired result is the max access (5).

Comment: Actually it is 5, sorry for the original typo.

Comment: It's ok, it was edited a lot and I was confused too for a bit

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Club
WHERE CLUB_ID =
    (SELECT Club_ID
     FROM Club_Intersect
     ORDER BY ACCESS DESC
     LIMIT 1);
```

I think that would work for selecting the club you want, using a nested SQL Query. You didn't specify what you wanted in your returned results, because this query would only retrieve the Club columns.